# QPixmap loadFromData() segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, qpixmap

```
 QZipReader reader(filename);

 QPixmap thumbnail;
 auto thumbnail_bytearr = reader.fileData("thumbnail.png");

 thumbnail.loadFromData(thumbnail_bytearr, "PNG");
```

Segmentation fault happens when **loadFromData** is called, and I cant understand why. Archive is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `loadFromData` with:

```
QFile out("thumbnail-out.png");
out.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.write(thumbnail_bytearr);
out.close();
```

Then make sure that the contents written to `thumbnail-out.png` are a valid PNG file. As long as libpng can read it, Qt should read it too. My hunch is that your `reader` returns broken, empty or invalid byte array.

Comment: Crashing would be still a bug and potential security problem though - so it would be interesting to have the data causing the crash, as test case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your problem is in extracting from archive but you better check it out by writing obtained byte array to .png file and checking if it's sane.

Anyway `QZipReader` is undocumented Qt class I'm not sure that it's appropriate to use it, because there is no guarantee or whatsoever. If you don't mind to use something outside of Qt I recommend [Minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) which is easy to use and also part of `zlib`.

Comment: I might agree with your advice of not using Qt internals, but the big benefit of Qt is that the application developer has full control of what's going on. After all, they chose the particular version, can diff the sources, and they run the upgrade cycle. It's a bit different if it were a Unix-packaged OSS project that uses the system Qt, but even then bundling your own Qt is not unheard of.

Comment: @KubaOber Yeah that's true but on the other hand if class is undocumented there's almost no way that some bugs were reported about it or that it was thoroughly tested. For example in this case it's hard for developer who decided to use it it to test if it works with all kinds of .zip files and there's almost no guarantee that library developers maintained those classes properly.

Comment: Agreed. It's a case of caveat emptor :)